# Why Flyway doesn't execute ALTER DATABASE?

Tags: mysql, flyway

I need update the character set of the database and the table also.

```
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;     

USE mydatabase;          
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `convert_table_charset`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE convert_table_charset()
BEGIN      
     IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = ‘mytable’) THEN
       ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
       ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
     END IF;
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
CALL convert_table_charset();
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `convert_table_charset`;
```

The script is executed with no errors.

```
2020-10-16 12:40:09,490 DEBUG --- [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] o.f.c.i.d.SqlScript : Found statement at line 1: ALTER DATABASE mydatabase CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
2020-10-16 12:40:09,495 DEBUG --- [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] o.f.c.i.d.SqlScript : Executing SQL: ALTER DATABASE mydatabase CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
2020-10-16 12:40:10,189 DEBUG --- [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] o.f.c.i.c.DbMigrate : Successfully completed and committed migration of schema `mydatabase` to version 220.0001
```

But *SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;* still returns an old value.

What am I doing wrong? **My tables were update correctly but the database wasn't and this statement works fine in Sequel Pro.**

- Flyway 3.2.1
- MySQL 5.6.47

Query

```
SHOW COLLATION WHERE Charset like 'utf8%';
```

One of the results is:

```
utf8mb4_unicode_ci  utf8mb4 224     Yes 8
```

Query

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';
```

Result

> innodb_version    5.6.47
>
> protocol_version  10
>
> slave_type_conversions
>
> version   5.6.47
>
> version_comment   Homebrew
>
> version_compile_machine   x86_64
>
> version_compile_os    osx10.15

Comment: You're changing the character set of a specific table, not the default character set of the server.

Comment: Those variables aren't specific to a table, they're the settings for the connection.

Comment: Did u read the first line of my script? The ALTER DATABASE is executed with no errors but the character set of the database still is an old value @Barmar

Comment: To follow up on @Akina's comment, try connecting to the database using the `mysql` command-line client or something similar and execute your ALTER DATABASE statement. This way the errors (if any) should be immediately apparent. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica There's no error when I execute the statement in Sequel Pro and it's updated correctly. Doesn't work only in Flyway.

Comment: I notice you are using an extremely old version of flyway (5 years old). I cannot guarantee it will be fixed in the latest version, but over the last few years a vast number of bugs have been fixed. Might be worth a try?